# Moving up and down on javascript based canvas game

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d

I am making game based on this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Workflows/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript

I think i understand how the paddle moves right and left. But when i try to make it move up and down, its not working at all. I have literally tried everyting but still its not working. So the question is how i can make it move up and down?

Here is the whole code:

```
    <script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("tausta");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
var paddleY = canvas.height-paddleHeight;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
    if(e.keycode == 38){
        upPressed = true;
    }
    if(e.keycode == 40){
        downPressed = true; 
    }
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
    if(e.keycode == 38){
        upPressed = false;
    }
    if(e.keycode == 40){
        downPressed = false; 
    }
}

function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function drawPaddle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(paddleX, paddleY, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBall();
    drawPaddle();

    if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
        dy = -dy;
    }

    if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {
        paddleX += 5;
    }
    if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
        paddleX -= 5;
    }
    if(upPressed && paddleY < canvas.height-paddleHeight) {
        paddleY += 5;
    }
    if(downPressed && paddleY > 0) {
        paddleY -= 5;
    }

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);

</script>
```

Comment: I think you reversed up and down. For going up you need to do paddleY -= 5;, for goign down paddleY += 5; (also switch the boundery conditions)

Comment: i have tried to do up -=5 and +=5, and down: +=5 and -=5. Nothing seems to happen. When i press upkey or downkey, nothing happens in game. Edit : But left and right works normally.

Comment: did you try removing '< canvas.height-paddleHeight' and 'paddleY > 0' from the up and down if-statements?

Comment: Now i tried but still nothing. If you meant this:                    if(upPressed) {
        paddleY -= 5;
    }
 if(downPressed ) {
  paddleY += 5;
    }

Comment: It does indeed have some strange behaviour. It might have to do with the variable being accessible becaus you are trying ot assign it too quickly. I'll check it out later. (testing fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cagwyd6m/1/)

Comment: Okay thanks. Let me know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple mistake.
You typed

```
if(e.keycode == 38){
if(e.keycode == 40){
```

But it should be

```
if(e.keyCode== 38){
if(e.keyCode== 40){
```

capital C

http://jsfiddle.net/cagwyd6m/4/

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. I have tried figure that like 3 days now. But thank you so much!